# How to handle huge data of sql in api

Tags: php, sql, angular

I need to know i created a simple api in php to fetch data from sql database. But the data is very huge. It will take so much time to get data in api(20minutes). Is their any way i need the data fastly.

I m creating api using it in angular application by http request.

Is their any other way to get data fast ?

Comment: use pagination concept, means to say get first 100-500(check how much time it takes and decide the number) first and then next 500-1000......etc. break down data into chunks instead of getting it all at a time

Comment: You shouldn't be getting all records at once. Keep the limit may max to 500 records initially and then as per request you should be fetching as needed.

Comment: Also check for indexing in database.

Answer (score 0):

If you did pagination and still your data are huge, there are other ways to make it faster.

`1- Gzip compression
 2- Streaming
 3- Multipart JSON
 4- Chunk data transferring (a kind of streaming)`